# trying to access weather API and display name and weather just the following code is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var api="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?";
function getWeather(lat,lon){
  var ustr = api + lat + "&" + lon;
  $.ajax({
    url: ustr, success:function(result){
      $("#place").text(result.name+",");
      $("#country").text(result.sys.country);
    }
  });
}
$( document ).ready(function(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var lat = "lat=" + position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = "lon=" + position.coords.longitude;
      getWeather(lat, lon);
    });
  } else {
    $("#place").html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }

})
```

unable to get name and country from this JavaScript please help
i even tried with j son function but dint displayed any result

Comment: do you get any results at all?

Comment: All works correctly. Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vegn2axd/

Comment: not working @IvanMinakov the issue in the code

Comment: @btc4cash - the fiddle works correctly

Comment: Is the page this is hosted in served using `https`? If not, chrome and firefox at least do not allow `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` - debugging 101 - check the **developer** tools console in your browser

Comment: @JaromandaX I use a VPN, I clicked allow localization as well. The var ustr is wrong

Comment: I don't care about VPN ... I care about how the page this code is on is served .... https? http? file? i.e. this code exists in a web page. you load the web page in your browser ... is it `file:///`, `http://` or `https://`

Comment: the val ustr is not wrong, check @IvanMinakov's fiddle that has your code in it ... it works!

Comment: i don't get any result so what i did is manually tried to check if ustr link created works or not and it actually works and return a object with various values that has required attributes that i want but i don't know in my code why isn't it displaying

Comment: and place were i load is https only

Comment: @JaromandaX ya it worked there but it isn't displaying in my code don't know why?even it is not displaying any error if it din't fetch the data

Comment: got it dint included jquery link and bootstrap sry